# Javascript pass in parameter issue

Tags: javascript

I have a script that looks like this:

```
var test = {
    something: function(m){ alert('m'); }
}
```

And I'd like to pass in a parameter (in this case the message to alert. I've tried the following but clearly I'm missing something:

```
test.something('This is my message...');
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are alerting a **string literal**. Remove the quote characters to make it a variable

```
alert(m);
```

Comment: Yeah, this was a case of "don't code until you're fully awake". I had the code right (the 'm' actually used the variable, not the string literal), I just had multiple functions and forgot to add the "," after each one.

Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: @KentSafranski: So the code in your question wasn't the actual code giving you trouble? Next time please take the time to verify that you've provided code that properly illustrates the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article to get started with javascript.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Also, note that m is not the same as 'm', which is a string consisting of the letter m rather than the variable m